# Can you actually use Rod of Ages on League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've recently started playing **League of Legends**, and soon realized that when you buy `Rod of Ages`, a number at the bottom right increases as you kill somebody I guess, like on the example of the image below.

But when you try to press - number `1` on the keyboard to use it like you use Zhonyas for example, nothing happens. Does this item actually works like that, or am I misunderstanding its concept?

[image]

Comment: If you hover your mouse pointer over items in the game, a tooltip will show detailing what the item does and how.

Comment: Why does this question get downvoted? It's a very basic question, but this is a Q&A site after all and question don't always need to be about professional stuff...and I think this is a very valid question for a beginner..

Comment: @Toby From the time I've spent playing the game I realized that the majority of LoL players are very negative and are always `"flaming"` other people, I think they are bringing the same attitude here as well...

Comment: @Chun I don't understand what you mean by negative attitude.. This was a simple question.

Comment: @Toby, I speculate that it has something to do with the author showing little to no personal research. I have seen this directly listed as a reason for down voting, and as Ender states, hovering over the item in-game actually tells you what it does. I do not think its fair to assume OP knows this, we can not assume their skill or experience with the game. But regardless, this is a valid question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Rod of Ages it's not an activatable item, you get 1 stack each minute for a maximum of 10, which gives you more ap, mana and life. The number 2 indicates that you have 2 stacks.

Comment: As a small addition: The number of a slot will turn yellow if an activatable item is present.

Comment: Yes, and now the completely slot turns like a dark color when you have an activatable item, but I think that it's a bad idea, because I always think that the item it's on cd :(

Answer (score 2):

Using the [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rod_of_Ages) for reference;

**The Rod of Ages gains +20 health, +40 mana and +4 ability power once a minute**, up to ten times. The number next to it represents how many times the item has "upgraded", giving you **a maximum of +200 health, +400 mana and +60 ability power, when the number reaches 10**.

The item gives completely passive benefits, and thus has no activation.

As a side note, the item also restores 150 health and 200 mana, over 8 seconds, when you level up. This benefit is "unique"; Having multiple Rod of Ages does not give you multiple restorations on level.